# Subroutine arguments as key-value pairs without a temp variable

Tags: perl, hash, subroutine, subroutine-prototypes

In Perl, I've always liked the key-value pair style of argument passing,

`fruit( apples => red );`

I do this a lot:

```
sub fruit {
    my %args = @_;
    $args{apples}
}
```

Purely for compactness and having more than one way to do it, is there a way to either:

- access the key-value pairs without assigning `@_` to a hash? I.e. in a single statement?
- have the subroutine's arguments automatically become a hash reference, perhaps via a subroutine prototype?

#### Without:

- assigning to a temp variable `my %args = @_;`
- having the caller pass by reference i.e. `fruit({ apples => red });`  *purely for aesthetics*

### Attempted

- `${%{\@_}}{apples}`

  Trying to reference `@_`, interpret that as a hash ref, and access a value by key.

  But I get an error that it's not a hash reference. (Which it isn't ^.^ ) I'm thinking of C where you can cast pointers, amongst other things, and avoid explicit reassignment.
- I also tried subroutine prototypes

  `sub fruit (%) { ... }`

  ...but the arguments get collapsed into `@_` as usual.

Comment: The `%` prototype is the same as the `@` prototype. `%` just has extra implications to the reader.

Comment: If you casted a pointer to an array into a pointer to a hash in C, you'd get segfault when you'd try to use that pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't perform a hash lookup (`${...}{...}`) without having a hash. But you could create an anonymous hash.

```
my $apples  = ${ { @_ } }{apples};
my $oranges = ${ { @_ } }{oranges};
```

You could also use the simpler post-dereference syntax

```
my $apples  = { @_ }->{apples};
my $oranges = { @_ }->{oranges};
```

That would be very inefficient though. You'd be creating a new hash for each parameter. That's why a named hash is normally used.

```
my %args = @_;
my $apples  = $args{apples};
my $oranges = $args{oranges};
```

An alternative, however, would be to use a hash slice.

```
my ($apples, $oranges) = @{ { @_ } }{qw( apples oranges )};
```

The following is the post-derefence version, but it's only available in 5.24+<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
my ($apples, $oranges) = { @_ }->@{qw( apples oranges )};
```

---

1. It's available in 5.20+ if you use the following:

   ```
   use feature qw( postderef );
   no warnings qw( experimental::postderef );
   ```

Comment: [Adding someone else's answer to your own to make a better answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35211/adding-someone-elses-answer-to-your-own-to-make-a-better-answer)

Comment: @cdlane, Technically, I just re-added information that was originally in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're more concerned about compactness than efficiency, you can do it this way:

```
sub fruit {
    print( +{@_}->{apples}, "\n" );

    my $y = {@_}->{pears};

    print("$y\n");
}

fruit(apples => 'red', pears => 'green');
```

The reason `+{@_}->{apples}` was used instead of `{@_}->{apples}` is that it conflicts with the `print BLOCK LIST` syntax of `print` without it (or some other means of disambiguation).

Comment: @ikegami Very interesting - I'd like to add that `{@_}->{apples}` also seems to conflict with the beginning of a new block, if it's on a line without a function name preceding it. It won't compile anyway. I never knew about the unary `+` operator - good stuff.

Comment: @iPherian, Unary `+` literally does nothing. It's not present at run-time; it doesn't even force scalar context. But it's useful in cases like this. A common place that needs disambiguation is `map`'s arguments. `map +{ ... }, LIST` is used to force the `map EXPR, LIST` syntax, and `map {; ... } LIST` is used to force the `map BLOCK LIST` syntax.